# Input field markup validation start with C or G

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to make a input field markup like C38777 or G38777

the field start with C or G and next 5 digits should be number is it possible ?

```
<input id="indexnumber" name="indexnumber" type="text" placeholder="Index number">
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need a regex to match your input with the pattern. The regex will be `^[CG][0-9]{5}$`.

Explanation:

```
^           # match beginning of string
 [CG]       # match a letter for the first char that is either C or G
[0-9]         # match for digit 
{5}          #number of digits required to match
```

You can use this

```
    $(function() {
    $('#btn').click(function() {
        var val = $('#indexnumber').val();
      var regex = new RegExp('^[CG][0-9]{5}$');
      if(!regex.test(val)) {
        alert('Failed')
      }
     });

})
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/mayank_shubham/sdnscyxz/)

To achieve this onkeyup event use this:

```
$(function() {
$('#indexnumber').on('keyup', function() {
    var val = $(this).val();
  var regex = new RegExp('^[CG][0-9]{5}$');
  if(regex.test(val)) {
    //Do Something
  }
 });

})
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/mayank_shubham/sdnscyxz/2/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer ! but is it possible something like onKeyup instead of button click ?

Comment: Instead of a .click() event you can use the onblur() on input text box or even an onkeyup() too. I will add that too in some time